# vwait is hanging even though variable is modified

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to run background process and wait for it to complete using `vwait`. To run background process, I'm using file event. When process completes the executation callback `testp` is called, in which I'm changing the variable which I'm waiting for. I can see that `echo "test callback"` getting printed but `vwait` is still hanging.

```
proc runCommand {callback cmd} {
    set f [open "| $cmd" r]
    fconfigure $f -blocking false
    fileevent $f readable  [list $callback $f]
}


proc testp {efile} {
 set test 1
 close $efile
 echo "test callback"  
}


runCommand testp "ls"
vwait test
```

Comment: try with `vwait ::test`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two *test* variables have a different scope. `set test 1` in the testp proc modifies a local variable. The `vwait` monitors a global *test* variable.

You can access the global *test* variable in a proc by adding `global test` inside the proc, or by referring to it with its fully qualified name (`set ::test 1`):

```
proc testp {efile} {
    global test
    set test 1
    close $efile
    echo "test callback"  
}
```